# No create session with Grails Spring Security and Database Session Plugin

Tags: database, session, grails, spring-security

I'm using grails 2.5.1 with Spring Security and Database Session Plugin , I don't know if it's working fine but in my db the tables created by Database Session Plugin doesn't have any data. I have this in my config in order to test in develop environment :
grails.plugin.databasesession.enabled=true
And if it's true , it's imposible login in to the web and the database has data in Database Session Plugin tables. And If it's false no data is saved in the tables and it's posible to login.

Thanks

Comment: I have face this issue before, my advice is not to use this plugin for scaling your application. My recommendation is to use spring-session plugin with redis or use it with hazelcast. If you prefer it to be handled by servlet, use payara as it has hazelcast built in.